# REST POST method design: query/form parameters vs. encapsulating content messages

Tags: design, rest, api

I am designing a `REST` `API` and facing a choice of formatting my `POST` methods to absorb parameters free-form via query string or content parameters:

```
POST /my/api HTTP/1.0

paramOne=XYZ&paramTwo=ABC
```

or expect that a rigidly formatted data message (XML/JSON) be posted which encapsulates parameters:

```
POST /my/api HTTP/1.0

<requestClass>
    <paramOne>XYZ</paramOne>
    <paramTwo>ABC</paramTwo>
</requestClass>
```

I have a preference for the second approach because it is cleaner (meaning a single code-level input argument vs multiple one, as well as basic format validation) and it also better accommodates data hierarchy (e.g. if `paramTwo` had sub entities, which, while not impossible, would be not so clean to implement in the query/form parameter approach):

```
<requestClass>
    <paramOne>XYZ</paramOne>
    <paramTwo>
        <subOne>1</subOne>
        <subTwo>2</subTwo>
    </paramTwo>
</requestClass>
```

So, my question is, other than styling preferences, are there any other considerations in deciding whether a REST POST method should be taking parameters or a single encapsulating message? Are there any basic guidelines which approach to implement depending on different factors or environment? For example, does one approach present more of a security vulnerability than the other (I have an inkling it doesn't because both the content and query string can be sniffed equally easily and, in case of HTTPS it doesn't matter) etc.?

If that matters, my services are written in `Java` and provided via `Apache CXF` running in `Tomcat 7`.

Comment: REST doesn't really have much to do with this.  What you are describing is simply POST, not REST POST (there is no such thing).

Comment: this REST madness has gone on long enough. just post everything and use the body not the query string

Comment: Erik Eidt's answer sheds some light why this being in a REST context matter

Comment: @Ewan -- that is my preference.  However, Erik in his answer makes a really good point about conforming the GET and POST URIs, which I really like, which gives some legitimacy to query params

Comment: don't use GET. ever

Comment: @Ewan: Then give up REST.  GET is the foundation by which REST-style architectures are able to retrieve resources in a reasonably standards-compliant way.  There's nothing wrong with using POST for everything, of course.  You just can't call that REST.

Comment: @Ewan -- why ?  do you just mean don't use it to create data ? I use it to return data

Comment: @amphibient: Note that, if you don't need the benefits that REST provides, then you don't need REST.  I haven't heard anything yet that demonstrates that you actually need REST compliance.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes its madness, no-one does full hateos REST anyway and arguing about which HTTP verb best matches the meaning of your api call is an exercise in futility

Comment: I will add that @bdsl makes a valid point in a comment to Erik's answer below. Sometimes, a POST will generate an entity whose identifier is unknown prior to the transaction so it it impossible to uniform the GET and POST URIs.  but my case is different and I do have a user assigned unique key (in addition to a sequence generated system ID)

Comment: Do you actually need REST compliance?  Why?

Comment: because I am using an API (JAX-RS via CXF) that i find convenient and that API serves REST by the standard of the API

Comment: If the client knows the URI in advance then I think PUT is often appropriate instead of POST. That has the constraint that the client shouldn't be accountable for any side effects caused by them PUTing the same content multiple times instead of once.

Comment: @RobertHarvey --  a longer answer is that I am not writing my own servlet that serves my API but using a lightweight framework that does most of the plumbing for me and it servers REST as a matter of its implementation. i hope that answers your question.  the framework does not necessarily enforce REST compliance but merely enables remote method invocation in a format more compact than, let's say SOAP

Comment: good point about the idempotence of a known URI, @bdsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one concrete difference between the two.

The length of the query string is severely limited (depending on what browser/server you are using) compared the the max size of a POST request

8000 characters might seem like a lot, but if you are sending lists of things with long parameter names you can soon run out.

Unless you have a defined number and max length of parameters you should use the request body

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking more broadly at both the POST and the GET, with an eye for some consistency for your API, especially since you are looking at REST.

Various identifiers of the desired information (resource) for the GET necessarily go in either the path or the query parameters as there is no body.

For the same parameters, I'd do the same for the POST as for GET so the URI is the same.  Other parameters that are not share between GET and POST could go either way, and perhaps are fine in the body instead of the URI.

Comment: I think the point about the URI for both the GET and POST being the same is very good

Comment: You don't generally want to POST and GET to exactly the same URI. POSTS often create new resources, and the server chooses what URI to give them. I might POST a new entry to https://myblog.com/posts/ but GET it from https://myblog.com/posts/345

Comment: that's a good point.  i do have a sequence generated integer ID but i also have a user assigned key in each record that must be unique.  So the `GET` is based off of that user chosen string, which would be a path parameter in both cases.

Comment: @bdsl, good point.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't describe the first option as free-form. It looks like you could tell your client to send data using the [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) encoding. This is the encoding web browsers use when submitting forms.

Both this and other encoding such as XML, JSON etc can work well, so I would choose whichever seems most convenient to reliably implement and clearly document. As you say, XML & JSON will generally work better than form-urlencoded for data with a tree structure.

You should be able to treat either encoding as a single input to your code. You don't say what programming language you are using, but I would expect any language used on the web to have way to get the request body as a string, which you should then be able to run through a decoding function for whatever format it was sent in.

Comment: using Java with CXF for service provision, good point, i will add that to the question